# Jquery - fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using Golive for my sites and Fancybox works good.But I have problems if in the same page (html or jsp pages) I put fancybox for my gallery AND Menumachine code for my menu.
When I put this code

```
<menumachine name="prova" id="m349do81">
    <csobj t="Component" csref="../menumachine/prova/menuspecs.menudata">
        <noscript> 
            <p><a class="mm_no_js_link" href="../menumachine/prova/navigation.html">Site Navigation</a></p>
        </noscript> 
    </csobj> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--var mmfolder=/*URL*/"../menumachine/",zidx=1000;//-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../menumachine/menumachine2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../menumachine/prova/menuspecs.js"></script>    
</menumachine>
```

Fancybox stop working !! I think there is somenthing in this code that I have to change or modify,but I don't know what!!
Please help me.
Cristina

Comment: I've formatted your code properly, and there's a missing `>` off the last closing script tag

Comment: :(( I tried again with this new menu code but does'nt work...

Comment: <menumachine name="menu" id="m349do8a">
    <csobj t="Component" csref="../menumachine/menu/menuspecs.menudata"><noscript>
      <p><a class="mm_no_js_link" href="../menumachine/menu/navigation.html">Site Navigation</a></p>
     </noscript> </csobj> 
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
var mmfolder=/*URL*/"../menumachine/",zidx=1000;
//--></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../menumachine/menumachine2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../menumachine/menu/menuspecs.js"></script>
   </menumachine>

Answer (score 0):

There are some documented issues when using menumachine and some jQuery scripts.

They suggested to add this to solve such conflict:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
 if(typeof(Array.shift)=="undefined")
 Array.shift = function(){};
</script>
```

You can read more on the [menumachine knowledge base](http://menumachine.com/kb/search.html?cat=1)

Comment: @user1165059 is this the right answer for you? please don't forget to mark it then  ;)